# Executing string sent from one terminal in another in Linux pseudo-terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, tty, xterm, pty

Lets say I have one terminal where the output of "tty" is "/dev/pts/2"
From another terminal, I want to send a command to the first terminal and execute it.
Using:
echo "ls" > "/dev/pts/2" only prints "ls" in the first terminal
Is there a way to execute the string?

Comment: I don't think so, because that would be a huge security hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; terminals don't execute commands. They're just channels for data.

You can sort of run a command and attach it to another terminal like this, though:

```
ls </dev/pts/2 >/dev/pts/2 2>/dev/pts/2
```

It won't behave *exactly* like you ran it from that terminal, though, as it won't have that device set as its controlling terminal. It's reasonably close, though.

Comment: Yes, the thing executing commands is the shell, not the terminal.

Comment: Thanks! didn't about just attaching the output to the terminal. It really helps.

Answer (score 1):

I realize it's a year late, but there is a simpler way I think.  Doesn't this work?

```
ls > /dev/pts/2
```

It works on my system.

Comment: This works for `ls`, because it doesn't accept input and usually doesn't display error messages. It won't work for more complex commands, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo `ls`
```

notice different quote sign.

Comment: those are back-tick not quotes

Answer (score 0):

Usually getty, login, and shell programs are needed for executing commands from tty.

But you can also put a shell directly executing commands from a pseudo terminal.
This is simplified example (all error checkings removed):

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int master_fd = create_my_own_psudo_terminal() ;

    // Wait until someone open the tty
    fd_set fd_rset;
    FD_ZERO( &fd_rset );
    FD_SET( master_fd, &fd_rset );
    select( master_fd + 1, &fd_rset, NULL, NULL, NULL );

    dup2( master_fd, STDIN_FILENO );
    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

Now you can do the following:

Start this simple program in the first terminal.

And send your command from the second terminal:

```
echo "ls" > /dev/pts/5
```

And you will get listing in the first terminal.

Note: This is quite unsecure, because login is not done.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute /bin/sh > /dev/pts/5  to get a shell in the pty, then execute other commands. If you want a true shell functionality, you could maybe implement a thread  (in a C program, with the openpty commands and all) to read the master pty and output its contents.