# Giving a command in a embedded terminal

Tags: python, button, window, tkinter

I'm using the following python code to embed a terminal window (from Ubuntu Linux) in a Tkinter window. I would like give the command 'sh kBegin' in the window automatically when the terminal window starts:

```
from Tkinter import *
from os import system as cmd

root = Tk()
termf = Frame(root, height=800, width=1000)

termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
wid = termf.winfo_id()
cmd('xterm -into %d -geometry 160x50 -sb &' % wid)

root.mainloop()
```

Pseudo:

```
cmd('xterm -into %d -geometry 160x50 -sb &' % wid)
embedded_terminal('sh kBegin')
# EMBEDDED TERMINAL DISPLAYS OUTPUT OF sh kBegin##
```

How would I get this working?

Comment: If you don't need to interact at all, you could use: `xterm -into ... -sb -hold -e sh kBegin`

Comment: @mgilson thanks, but I do need to interact with the terminal and it returned an error using the -font tag as well: "xterm -font -adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--18-180-75-75-m-110-iso8859-1 -into %d -geometry 88x37 -sb -hold -e sh kBegin". I need to be able to send commands from say.. A button press in Tkinter enters the text "Hello World && <ENTER>" into the terminal. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: If you can do that, I'm quite interested in the solution as well!  I've often wondered if it's possible to embed an arbitrary x11 window inside a tkinter widget ... I think that would be pretty nifty too...

Comment: This gets you a little further: `xterm ... -e "sh kBegin;bash"`, but not much.  I'm not sure if you're going to get much further though... (reference) http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/669765

Comment: @mgilson Haha sweet, if I do manage to get anywhere; I'll let you know. I may end up just resorting to a more powerful gui kit, as I don't seem to be having any luck at all (except for what you just suggested). I did manage to set something up using sockets and multiple threads; it just feels a little pointless having to do that.

Comment: see also [tkterminal](https://github.com/Saadmairaj/tkterminal), a Terminal widget for Tkinter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can interact with a shell by writing in the pseudo-terminal slave child. Here is a demo of how it could works. This answer is somewhat based on an answer to [*Linux pseudo-terminals: executing string sent from one terminal in another*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8677671/428236).

The point is to get the pseudo-terminal used by xterm (through `tty` command) and redirect output and input of your method to this pseudo-terminal file. For instance `ls < /dev/pts/1 > /dev/pts/1 2> /dev/pts/1`

Note that

1. xterm child processed are leaked (the use of `os.system` is not recommended, especially for `&` instructions. See [`suprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)).
2. it may not be possible to find programmatically which tty is used
3. each commands are executed in a new suprocess (only input and output is displayed), so state modification command such as `cd` have no effect, as well as context of the xterm (`cd` in the xterm)

```
from Tkinter import *
from os import system as cmd

root = Tk()
termf = Frame(root, height=700, width=1000)
termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
wid = termf.winfo_id()

f=Frame(root)
Label(f,text="/dev/pts/").pack(side=LEFT)
tty_index = Entry(f, width=3)
tty_index.insert(0, "1")
tty_index.pack(side=LEFT)
Label(f,text="Command:").pack(side=LEFT)
e = Entry(f)
e.insert(0, "ls -l")
e.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X,expand=1)

def send_entry_to_terminal(*args):
    """*args needed since callback may be called from no arg (button)
   or one arg (entry)
   """
    command=e.get()
    tty="/dev/pts/%s" % tty_index.get()
    cmd("%s <%s >%s 2> %s" % (command,tty,tty,tty))

e.bind("<Return>",send_entry_to_terminal)
b = Button(f,text="Send", command=send_entry_to_terminal)
b.pack(side=LEFT)
f.pack(fill=X, expand=1)

cmd('xterm -into %d -geometry 160x50 -sb -e "tty; sh" &' % wid)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow! That worked perfectly! Thanks heaps! I'm going to have a play around with what you provided, and manifest it to work to my needs. But that instance worked spot on. Thank you :)