# Input terminal command to embedded terminal in GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm pretty new to Python, so bear with me on this. I looked at the possible duplicate of my question, and wasn't able to get it to work for me. I'm assuming I just don't understand the answer code enough, but I can't seem to get the terminal command I want, just the one used in the answer.

The answer I'm referring to can be found here: [Giving a command in a embedded terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239965/giving-a-command-in-a-embedded-terminal)

I've got a simple GUI that I've embedded a terminal into. The purpose of this is to run tcpdump to capture packets. I wrote a simple script that did this just fine, but I'm looking to make it easier to use on a touch screen, hence the GUI.

I set up a button that runs the following code:

```
os.system('sudo tcpdump')
```

But it doesn't execute in the embedded terminal.

Could someone explain how to make this command run in the terminal that's embedded in the GUI?

Here's all the code I have for the GUI so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

class PcapGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Packet Captures")

        self.start_button = Button(master, text="Start", command=self.start)

        self.termf = Frame(root, height=400, width=500)

        self.wid = self.termf.winfo_id()

        os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 70x20 -sb &' % self.wid)

    def start(self):
        os.system('sudo tcpdump')


root = Tk()
gui = PcapGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you _really_ need an embedded terminal, or do you just need a way to run a command and see its output?

Comment: My boss would prefer I use an embedded terminal, so unless it isn't achievable I'd like to use one. Programming isn't really my forte, which is why I only recently learned python.